# Laravel mix recompiles all assets even though only a css change is made

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using laravel-mix 1.0 in a laravel 5.6 project to compile my sass and javascript, however, each time I make a change in the sass, it compiles both sass and js, making the compilation process increasingly slower as the project grows.

I tried it with the default minimum mix configuration, but I still get the same result. Surely, mix must be able to do something as simple as splitting the two compilation processes, since it was a breeze to make it work in Gulp.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 4):

disabling url processing it fixed the issue for me, back to seconds compared to the painfully slow minutes it was taking before building bootstrap-sass on windows.

If only I'd checked the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix) earlier. All my urls are absolute and very rarely change.

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/app/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .options({
      processCssUrls: false
   });
```

Comment: This does not make them compile separately